# Can we have the correct prefix for "people reached"?

Tags: bug

[image]

Of course, this should be capital M from mega, not the lower case m from milli!

Comment: It's not a unit of measurement; it's only a quantity. There's so much thing as "***M***ega-people". The `m` is just shorthand for "million", not "mega".

Comment: @KingDuken I think people is used as unit of measurement. But still, where does the k stand for in 23k people reached?

Comment: [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) qualifies as a *megaperson*. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a system-level issue that you'll have to raise on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks. It's on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340764/can-we-have-the-correct-prefix-for-people-reached now